# Grub rescue can't write outside of disk "hd0"

Tags: installation, boot, live-usb, grubrescue

I tried to install Ubuntu 13.04 from a Live USB, and it said it was successfully installed, and after the reboot I got an error message that said:

```
error: attempt to read or write outside of disk "hd0"
grub rescue
```

I am new to Ubuntu. Please help.